# Label following arrow in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to write diagonal arrows, with the label lay down to the arrow.

Something like this:

[image]

Here is my best attempt, but it does not work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0,0) {$\bullet$};
    \node (B) at (-2,-1) {$\bullet$};
    \draw[thick,->] (A) -- (B) node[midway,sloped,rotate=270] {$\frac 34$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I just get this:

[image]

Comment: If you need it just once (or twice) you could use a `xshift` and `yshift` per node, but it doesn't make much sense for many nodes.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just add `left`. Normally you'd want `above`, but because of the rotation you need `left`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0,0) {$\bullet$};
    \node (B) at (-2,-1) {$\bullet$};
    \draw[thick,->] (A) -- (B) node[midway,sloped,left,rotate=270] {$\frac{3}{4}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```